# Why does Wpglobus plugin's meta data not get stored in database when I update my custom post?

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

I am unable to store [Wpglobus plugins](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wpglobus/)'s meta data into database. I have created a custom post and I have use Wpglobus plugin for translation my content into other language. But when updating my custom post, the meta data of this plugin is not stored in database.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What is "meta data of this plugin"?

Comment: I've added some tags, fixed a little the grammar, and added link to the plugin to get more attention on this question

Comment: Prabhdeep already asked this question on WPGlobus support forum on WordPress.org.